# django shell not fully executing script

Tags: python, django, shell

I have a script (`script.py`) that looks like the following:

```
array = []
for item in table:
    array.append([item.name,item.pk])
for row in array:
    print row
```

when I run `python manage.py shell < script.py`, everything runs fine except:

```
for row in array:
    print row
```

never executes. if I change that to `print array`, it prints the full array no problem. How is this happening? it makes no sense to me.

EDIT:

if I change it to a one liner:

```
for row in array: print row
```

the script executes just fine. I would really like to understand how this is possible.

Comment: I feel like you've probably left out too much information for someone to be able to reasonably answer this. Could you post your real `script.py`?

Comment: I cannot, it is confidential. I gave you the general scope. I create a 2D array. Populate it. and then try and print out each row. If I print the whole array, it prints, if I try and loop through to print each row, it does not

Comment: Could you please give us an example of code that will actually exhibit this behaviour (the given example is incomplete)

Comment: Maybe it's to do with the script.py format. Do you use space-tabs or plain tabs ?

Comment: @SteveK I use tabs. This exact same script has worked before and it just started doing this. It makes no sense

Comment: @RobertJørgensgaardEngdahl I have edited code to do something in the other loop

Comment: Does your edit work in the other loop ?
I was expecting you would be using tabs. Can you try with space-tabs ?
I have an idea. Your goal is to execute a script in a Django environment, yes ? If so, would you prefer calling the script directly without injecting it to the django shell ?

Comment: The actual script requires django. `table` is a QS